# FragmentManager on orientation change behavior

Tags: java, android

I'm coding back navigation for fragments and i have this method for it:

```
private void removeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (activity == null) return;

        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(fragment)
                .commit();
}
```

It works' fine when i start app and do the navigation. But when i rotate device - this method stops working. Remove method called, but fragment remains on screen. Can't figure out why. Need some help)

method contained it this class -

```
public final class NavigationManager implements Navigation {

    private final Stack<NavigationFragment> fragments;

    @Nullable
    private AppCompatActivity activity;

    ////

    public NavigationManager() {
        this.fragments = new Stack<>();
    }

    //// NAVIGATION

    @Override
    public void setNavigationMechanism(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        if (fragments.size() <= 1 || activity == null) return;
        fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1).onBecomeVisible();
    }

    @Override
    public void navigateTo(NavigationFragment fragment, boolean isReplacing) {
        if (isReplacing) {
            removeFragment(fragments.pop());
            addFragment(fragment);
        }
        else addFragment(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void navigateBack() {
        if (activity == null) return;

        if (fragments.size() <= 1) {
            activity.finish();
            return;
        }

        removeFragment(fragments.pop());
        fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1).onBecomeVisible();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHardwareBackButtonClicked() {
        if (activity == null) return;

        if (fragments.size() <= 1) {
            activity.finish();
            return;
        }

        removeFragment(fragments.pop());
        fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1).onBecomeVisible();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationRevoked() {
        fragments.clear();
        try { addFragment(new AuthenticationFragment()); }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) { if (activity != null) activity.finish(); }
    }

    ////

    private void addFragment(NavigationFragment navigationFragment) {
        if (activity == null) return;

        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container_frame_layout, (Fragment) navigationFragment)
                .commit();
        fragments.add(navigationFragment);
        navigationFragment.onBecomeVisible();
    }

    private void removeFragment(NavigationFragment navigationFragment) {
        if (activity == null) return;

        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove((Fragment) navigationFragment)
                .commit();

        activity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_frame_layout).invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Method stops working or the app?

Comment: In the case of you rotating the screen, whether activity object is null?

Comment: Are you setting the activity's configchanges? in your manifest?

Comment: show your activity

Comment: 1) This method is part of NavigationManager class - it has field Activity activity, which set when activity created, so at the moment of method call - activity is not null (checked).
2) Manifest for activity - 
<activity android:name=".presentation.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `activity` variable is loosing it's instance when you change configuration. A possible work around is to set it in `onConfigurationChanged()` inside your activity.

First, make you `activity` variable public

```
public AppCompatActivity activity;
```

Inside your Activity add the following:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    NavigationManager.activity = this;
}
```